# OpenERP add field from other object

Tags: treeview, openerp-8

I am in debug mode, openerp v8, trying to edit the product.product.tree view (and probably search view) to also show the field product_code from the product.supplierinfo.

Can anyone help me with this or point me to a tutorial for it ?